# How to : click on div to go to other divs

Tags: html

I want to make a button with which button to can go scroll over the page on all elements.
I mean .. if you click for first time to go to the div 1 when you click twice to go to the other div or something like this.

I try to use on click go to target via # but i can`t make it go over all divs on click.
The scroll to the element can be via pixels which mean if first click is to scroll 300 pixels or scroll ticks down other to be 300 + 300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you searching something like this:

```
http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin
```

I suppose this to you is very easy to use. I hope this will help you.

Comment: this is exactly what i searching for thank you about that rly !

Comment: @Jerico No problem :) Can you mark my answer with thick ? thanks a lot

Comment: do u have skype for future response ? add me if u want bboy-slay is mine